# How sinusoidal wave relates with wheel mathematically?

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

Wheel has parameters $v$ velocity, $r$ radius, and the sinusoidal has $a$ amplitude and $f$ is frequency.

Comment: Can you give some clarification of what you are looking for.  A general sort of paremetic equation for a wheel would be $(x,y) = r(\cos \omega t, \sin \omega t).  r$ is the radius of the wheel, and $\omega$ is the angular speed, and $r\omega$ is the speed that a point on the edge of the wheel is moving.

Comment: x=sin (wt) is signal have frequency f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have a wheel with radius $R$ spinning with angular frequency $\omega$ in time. Then, a point $P$ on the rim of the wheel forms an angle $\theta(t)$ with the positive $x$-axis such that $\theta(t) = \omega t$. Hence, this point can be described with the parametric equations
$$
x(t) = R\cos\omega t \\
y(t) = R\sin\omega t.
$$
If we plot either of $x(t)$ or $y(t)$ as a function of time, the resulting graph is a sinusoidal wave, as we can clearly see based on these parametric equations, while the plot of $P(t)$ would be a circle of radius $R$.

The velocity of the point $P(t)$ is $\dot P(t) = \omega R(-\sin\omega t,\cos\omega t)$, and the *linear speed* of the point $P(t)$ is
$$
v = \sqrt{(-\omega R \sin\omega t)^2 + (\omega R\cos\omega t)^2} = \omega R
$$
where we have made use of the identity $\sin^2x + \cos^2x = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume a point on the unit circle. In the following picture you can see the relation of the angle that the pint makes with origin $(\theta)$ and the two functions $\sin(\theta)$ and $\cos(\theta)$

[image]

You can use this to understand the answer by AOrtiz.